# nicematrix: handle with empty cells / drawing lines into a NiceArray

Tags: matrices, arrays, nicematrix

[image]

I would like to add/draw lines (like the shown red one) over **and** under the letters A, B and D (not at the `\cdots`) - ***each to the upper and lower end of the matrix***.

*What is nicematrix's correct method for that?*

· There seems to be a problem at drawing at "empty cells". Does nicematrix know a key like TikZ-matrix's `nodes into empty cells` ?

· *Can I do that task elegantly with a foreach-loop?*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
$\begin{NiceArray}{(c c c c) }
    &     &           &      \\
A  & B  & \cdots  & D     \\
    &     &           &      \\
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
%\draw[red] (2-1) -- (1-1); % does not work-->' No shape named `1-1' is known.'
\draw[red] (2-1) -- (1.5|-1); % work
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe use relative coordinates, such as `\draw[red] (2-1) -- ++(0,-0.5) (2-1) -- ++(0,0.5);`? Should the lines be automatically drawn without explicity stating each cell?

Comment: There is no key in `nicematrix` in order to specify that all the "cell nodes" should be created (even in the empty cells) but it's possible to put the command `\NotEmpty` in a cell to specify that that cell should not be considered as empty (and a PGF/Tikz node will be  created).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Tikz instruction `\draw (2-1) -- (1-|1.5) ;` seems good (if I actually understand what you want to draw...).

For a loop, it's possible (for example) to use a `foreach` loop (provided by `pgffor` which is loaded by `pgf`, itself loaded by `nicematrix`).

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{(c c c c)}
  \NotEmpty  &     &           &      \\
A  & B  & \cdots  & D     \\
    &     &           &      \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [red]
   \foreach \i in {1,...,\value{jCol}} 
      { 
        \draw (2-\i) -- (1-|\i.5) ; 
        \draw (2-\i) -- (last-|\i.5) ; 
      } ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

In the `\CodeAfter` the LaTeX counter `jCol` contains the total number of columns of the array (whereas in the body of the array, it contains the number of the current column).

[image: Output of the above code]

You say in your question that you don't want any rule above and below the `\cdots`. Of course, the previous code does not automatically detect the command `\cdots` in the cell... Do you actually want a code with an automatic detection of the position of the potential commands `\cdots` (it's possible to write a code with such feature, but it's not straightforward)?